# How to add only attack bonus to a homebrew magic weapon in D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, attack, dnd-beyond

What Modifier and Modifier subtype can I use to give a weapon a +1 ***just*** to the attack/to-hit value in D&D Beyond? I don't want it to be +1 to-hit ***and*** +1 to damage, I ***just*** want the +1 to-hit.

I tried using "Bonus - Melee Weapon Attacks" but that applied the +1 to EVERY weapon wielded by the character wielding my homebrew magic weapon, when I want it to only apply to the homebrew weapon.

Comment: Returning to the question at hand.. @Kenny, I presume you are using Roll20 with the community-created character sheet template (v1.1.4) for 5th Edition, correct?

Answer (score 6):

There is a way, although not trivial, and does not happen on the create item page.

1. Add the weapon to your inventory
2. "Wield" the weapon, this should add it to your attacks
3. In the attack list, open the "Customize" menu, and there you can add bonuses that only applies to the to hit value of the weapon.